# How to pass partial view data within a view of different model type to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a ViewModel consisting of the 'List' entity and an array of 'Book' objects to the 'Create' Post method in my controller. The post will return the list but not any books. I'm not sure if I'm setting this up correctly or if I'm using the wrong model for the partial view.

ListWithBooksViewModel:

```
public class ListWithBooksViewModel
{
    public BookList List { get; set; }
    public Book[] Books { get; set; }
}
```

'Create' View:

```
@model LitList.Models.ListWithBooksViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "List", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>List Name: @Html.EditorFor(l => l.List.ListName)</div>
    <div>Subject of List: @Html.EditorFor(l => l.List.Subject)</div>

    Html.RenderPartial("AddBookPartial");
    Html.RenderPartial("AddBookPartial");
    Html.RenderPartial("AddBookPartial");

<p align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="Create List" />
</p>
}
```

'AddBookPartial' Partial View:

```
@model LitList.Domain.Entities.Book

@Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookName)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublicationYear)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublicationYear)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

'Create' ActionMethod:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ListWithBooksViewModel newList)
    {
        BookList list = newList.List;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var b in newList.Books)
            {
                b.ListRefId = list.ListId;
            }
            list.Books = newList.Books;
            listRepo.SaveList(list);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", list.ListName);
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Fail");
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically add new `Book` objects to tour collection  (in which case your doing it all wrong)

Comment: @Noah Harnak , just one thing do you want multiple book create form ??

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm trying to create a 'BookList' object that contains 'Book' objects. I have two tables, one for each entity and made a FK in the 'Books' table in hopes of creating a one-to many relationship. I'm still pretty novice to MVC so if you could give me a sense of direction on a different approach I should take, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Start with  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308). I'll add a link with a more detailed answer using `BeginCollectionItem` shortly

Comment: Refer also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/a-partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, Thank You! It's working now, those links really helped out a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you cannot have "**nested forms**" or BeginForm inside a BeginForm.

You are nesting the BeginForm inside a PartialView with another BeginForm.

You can refer to this link as additional reference: [Html.BeginForm inside of Html.BeginForm MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969740/html-beginform-inside-of-html-beginform-mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

Plese add the loop and just add on **RenderPartial** pass your object.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "List", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>List Name: @Html.EditorFor(l => l.List.ListName)</div>
    <div>Subject of List: @Html.EditorFor(l => l.List.Subject)</div>
    foreach (var book in Books)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("AddBookPartial", book);
    }
    <p align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Create List" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: That will not work at all. Suggest you read the links in the question comments.

Comment: The 'Books' property of the 'ListWithBooksViewModel' returns null because it doesn't contain any books. I used ListWithBooksViewModel in hopes of passing the 'Book' objects created by the partial view and the List object created by the 'Create' view.

Comment: yes @NoahHornak add the condition for book array and check if array is not null.